# LiipImagine filter not working on deployed symfony 5 site

Tags: symfony, ovh, liipimaginebundle

Junior developer here, thanks for your help.

I am trying to use the LiipImagine bundle for Symfony5 to reduce the quality of images uploaded by users to my site and therefore improve global load speed.

The filter works for APP_ENV=dev and APP_ENV=prod on localhost. But after transfer (ftp) to the server (OVHcloud kimsufi2015) the imagine quality filter is no longer applied.

Here is the URL for the first time the image is served to page

```
http://www.mycavebx.info/media/cache/resolve/my_large/uploads/images/grapeHand-5ecb7c476352f.jpeg
```

And the second time

```
http://www.mycavebx.info/media/cache/my_large/uploads/images/grapeHand-5ecb7c476352f.jpeg
```

Here is my liip_imagine.yaml

```
# app/config/config.yml

liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~

        my_large:
            default_image: defaultImage.jpg
            quality: 1
            filters:
                thumbnail: 
                    size: [1920, 1080]
                    mode: outbound
```

To debug i have tried :

- Checking prod error log in var folder, no related error messages.
- I don't think it is a permission issue, as i have changed chmod of all folders and files in public to 777.
- Specifically defining web root as `%kernel.project_dir%/public`, cache prefix as `media/cache`
- adding asset to TWIG template `<img src="{{ asset('/relative/path/to/image.jpg')`

**Does anyone else have experience using LiipImagine on kimsufi2015 ? It is possible that the server simply doesn't support this kind of cache image-filtering setup.**

**If yes, can anyone suggest a fix ?**

This is my first stackoverflow question. I hope i was clear.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the system is properly configured?

Comment: May be it's a permission access, have try to create media directory manually and give it 777 as permission ?

Comment: I'm so new to this i didn't even see these comments ! I have edited the topic to include the permission modification that i tried.

Comment: Nico Haase i have added a list of things i have tried to debug. I don't know how to check whether the system is properly configured or not. Can you please elaborate ?